# How to show all year, months as ints between two dates?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

In SQL Server 2000, I need to list out the year, month as ints in a temp table from orders of a customer.

If the month doesn't exist I still need to list the year, month, $0.00.

What is the best way to do this in SQL Server 2000?

`01/01/2010` to `07/01/2010` would yield:

```
__Year__, __Month__ , __Billed__
2010,1,$5000.00
2010,2,$6000.00
2010,3,$8000.00
2010,4,$0.00
2010,5,$4000.00
2010,6,$4500.00
```

using this code:

```
select grp.* from 
(
    select year(orderdate) as yr, 
           month(orderdate) as mn, 
           sum(billed) 
    from Orders 
    group by year(orderdate), month(orderdate), billed 
) grp
order grp.yr, grp.mn
```

Is there a simple solution to not skip months where there was no billing and add $0.00?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a numbers table containing numbers from 0 to 100,000 or whatever.

Then something like this:

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATE
DECLARE @EndDate AS DATE

SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(m, Numbers.N, @StartDate))
    ,MONTH(DATEADD(m, Numbers.N, @StartDate))
    ,ISNULL(OrderSummary.Billed, 0) AS Billed
FROM Numbers
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT year(orderdate), month(orderdate), sum(billed)
    FROM Orders
    GROUP by year(orderdate), month(orderdate)
) AS OrderSummary (Yr, Mn, Billed)
ON YEAR(DATEADD(m, Numbers.N, @StartDate)) = OrderSummary.Yr
    AND MONTH(DATEADD(m, Numbers.N, @StartDate)) = OrderSummary.Mn
WHERE Numbers.N < DATEDIFF(m, @StartDate, @EndDate)
```

A little easier in 2005 using common table expressions.

Comment: Also, regarding the numbers, I can count the number of months that exists between the start and stop date and just add that to a temporary "Numbers" table.

Comment: When you just have a max of a dozen numbers, you don't necessarily need to build a table of numbers (though they are useful) - if you need to port this around to different environments (not all of which might already have a numbers table) you can use something built in to generate the numbers.

Comment: @RetroCoder A table of numbers already indexed in appropriate ways can just sit around.  You may also actually permanently have a table of dates - this is certainly true in data warehouse environments.

Comment: I just use the datediff by month to get the total number of months between the daterange.  Also do you happen to have that second version for 2005?

Comment: @RetroCoder I would use CTEs like Aaron's answer in 2005.

Answer (score 5):

For 2005+ (sorry I missed the 2000 requirement):

```
DECLARE @Orders TABLE(OrderDate DATETIME, billed INT);

INSERT @Orders SELECT '20100104', 500
         UNION SELECT '20100106', 700;

DECLARE 
  @year INT, 
  @end_month TINYINT;

SELECT 
  @year = 2010, 
  @end_month = 7;

WITH s(n) AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (@end_month) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
    FROM sys.objects ORDER BY [object_id]
),
m(s) AS
(
  SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, n-1, DATEADD(YEAR, @year-1900, 0)) 
    FROM s
)
SELECT 
    [Year]  = @year, 
    [Month] = MONTH(m.s),
    Billed  = COALESCE(SUM(t.billed), 0)
FROM m
  LEFT OUTER JOIN @Orders AS t
  ON t.OrderDate >= m.s
  AND t.OrderDate < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, m.s)
GROUP BY
  MONTH(m.s)
  ORDER BY [Year], [Month];
```

For 2000 it's only slightly different:

```
CREATE TABLE #Orders(OrderDate DATETIME, billed INT);

INSERT #Orders SELECT '20100104', 500
         UNION SELECT '20100106', 700;

DECLARE 
  @year INT, 
  @end_month TINYINT;

SELECT 
  @year = 2010, 
  @end_month = 7;

SELECT 
    [year]  = @year, 
    [month] = MONTH(m.s),
    billed  = COALESCE(SUM(t.billed), 0)
FROM 
(
    SELECT s = DATEADD(MONTH, n-1, DATEADD(YEAR, @year-1900, 0)) FROM 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT TOP 12 n = number
          FROM master..spt_values 
          WHERE number BETWEEN 1 AND @end_month
              ORDER BY number
    ) 
    AS s
) AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN #Orders AS t
ON t.OrderDate >= m.s
AND t.OrderDate < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, m.s)
GROUP BY MONTH(m.s);
```

Now admittedly I don't have a 2000 instance handy to test - this is just off the cuff.

Comment: CTE's aren't valid in 2000 are they?

Comment: Oops, I saw the tags 2005 and 2008.

Comment: That's the hazard of tagging your question with every possible version!

Comment: @JNK Yep. Anyway, updated with a version that will work on 2000 (I think).

Comment: @JNK can you hear me from there? "MWU-HA-HA-HAAAA"

Comment: I sure can, RI isn't too far from CT

Comment: @JNK let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2819/discussion-between-aaron-bertrand-and-jnk)